# Why am I not getting the result back from this mongodb insert command?

Tags: mongodb

I am following a old tutorial. In the tutorial he is `inserting the data` and `console out the result` at the same time with the callback.

But I am not getting console.log even though the data goes into the db. Can someone take a look at my code

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const uri = "*****";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db("task-manager");
    const tasksCollection = database.collection("tasks");

    // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { title: "Back to the Future" };
    const movie = await tasksCollection.findOne(query);

    tasksCollection.insertMany(
      [
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2011",
        },
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2012",
        },
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2013",
        },
      ],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log("Unable to insert");
        }
        // RETURN NOTHING, I DON"T SEE CONSOLE.LOG
        return console.log(result.insertedIds);
      }
    );
  } 
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: Did you await the `insertMany` call like [this official example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertMany/#insert-multiple-documents)?

Comment: @ray Its doesn't seem to work. I tried adding `await` at the front. But the callback doesn't work at all

Comment: Did you strictly follow the official example I provided? Can you post your latest attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using callbacks are from [legacy versions](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#insertMany) of the Node.js native driver.

Please refer to [more recent](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.3/#md:insert-a-document) versions of the Node.js native driver API.

1. Delete this:

```js
tasksCollection.insertMany(
      [
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2011",
        },
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2012",
        },
        {
          title: "Tom & Jerry 2013",
        },
      ],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log("Unable to insert");
        }
        // RETURN NOTHING, I DON"T SEE CONSOLE.LOG
        return console.log(result.insertedIds);
      }
    );
```

2. Adopt a more modern approach with `async/await` like so:

```js
const results = await tasksCollection.insertMany([
   {
      title: "Tom & Jerry 2011",
   },
   {
      title: "Tom & Jerry 2012",
   },
   {
      title: "Tom & Jerry 2013",
   },
]);
console.log('Inserted Documents Result: ', results);
```

3. Your function can be improved to use `try/catch` within a single `async` function like so:

```js
async function run() {
   try {
      const database = client.db("task-manager");
      const tasksCollection = database.collection("tasks");

      // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
      const query = { title: "Back to the Future" };
      const movie = await tasksCollection.findOne(query);

      const results = await tasksCollection.insertMany([
         {
            title: "Tom & Jerry 2011",
         },
         {
            title: "Tom & Jerry 2012",
         },
         {
            title: "Tom & Jerry 2013",
         },
      ]);
      return results;
   } catch(err){
      throw err;
   }
}

run().then(results => {
   console.log('Inserted Documents Result: ', results);
}).catch(err =>{
   console.log(err);
})
```